# Where's the 'too minor edit' reject option?

Tags: support

If I'm not mistaken, there used to be a 'Too minor' edit reject option. Was this reject option removed? And why?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is gone.**

Discussion on Meta.se ([Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149722/226928)) about the problems with the “Too Minor” edit reject reason led to this proposal:

> **Get rid of the “too minor” reject reason entirely.** If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!

This option seems to have been popular enough for the SE staff to enact it, so now we have one less reason for rejecting edits.

Discussion about what you should use instead, if anything, can be found in the Meta.se question [What should be used in place of "Too Minor?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106/226928)

Comment: And good riddance!

Comment: Let me guess, the 6-character requirement for low-rep users is still there?

Comment: @Izkata I believe so.